# pandas transform moving average daily base to weekly base

Tags: pandas, statistics, data-science

I have a moving average with data points on everyday base e.g. 14 days MA.
Now I want to take this MA and display it on a bar chart e.g. one bar represents a week.

How I calculate the MA for this bar? 
Is it the sum of the daily MA points over the week?
1,2,3,4,5,6,7

So the MA is 28? but the base is still daily?
Can someone try to explain if this makes sense and is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Moving Average (MA) for the bar is the average of daily MA (daily count).
So

```
# Calculating MA

MA(week1) = (MA1 + MA2 + MA3 + MA4 + MA5 + MA6 + MA7)/7
MA(week1) = (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7)/7 = 4

# Bar value 4
```

Incase your data is 14-day MA, you will have to make some assumptions and calculate the weekly MA. Have a look at the example to get a better understanding.

```
# 14-day MA -> Weekly MA

 (W1 + W2)/2  = MA1
 (W2 + W3)/2  = MA2
    ...
(Wn-1 + Wn)/2 = MAn-1

# Assume W1 == W2, you can estimate the per weekly MA
```

[Example to calculate Moving Average](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/movingaverage.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but then the MA is describing the MA on daily base but I want it to describe the week. Then this is just the sum without dividing the days right?
MA(week1) = (MA1 + MA2 + MA3 + MA4 + MA5 + MA6 + MA7)
MA(week1) = (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7) = 28

Comment: It's the `average` that is the `(sum of days)/(number of days)`. 
So `MA(week1) = (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7)/7 = 4`